# Receive a Base64 encoded image in Django Rest Framework and save into ImageField

Tags: django, json, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to receive an image from an app, and the best way I can think of is to send it into a JSON array encoded in Base64. The image is very small so I don't care about the extra overhead.

I have a model :

```
class Observation(models.Model):    
    ...
    sonogram_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=sonogram_dir)
```

And its serialiser:

```
class ObsvSerializerNoDetect(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Observation
```

Where should I put the code to decode the image?

Comment: Yes and no. I store the image as text and then rendering it to a web page is pretty easy, in the `img` tag you put `src="data:image/png;base64,<your base64 string here>"`. I'm not sure it's the best way but it works fine and is easy to implement.

Comment: @gozzilli could you provide snippest with view/serializer/models of your base64-based solution?

Comment: My answer here may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027093/django-rest-serialize-a-text-or-image-file-to-post-via-http-in-json/26405078#26405078

Answer (score 26):

Here is how you can handle a Base64 encoded image file in a post request at the Django-based (drf also) API end which saves it as an ImageField.

Let say you have a Model as follows:

```
class MyImageModel(models.Model):
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'geo_entity_pic')
      data=model.CharField()
```

So the Corresponding Serializer would be as follows:

```
 from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField

 class MyImageModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializers):
      image=Base64ImageField() # From DRF Extra Fields
      class Meta:
         model=MyImageModel
         fields= ('data','image')
      def create(self, validated_data):
        image=validated_data.pop('image')
        data=validated_data.pop('data')
       return MyImageModel.objects.create(data=data,image=image)
```

The corresponding View can be as follows:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = MyImageModelSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Notice In the Serializer  I have used Implementation of Base64ImageField provided in the module [django-extra-field](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extra-fields/)

To install this module run the command

```
pip install django-extra-fields
```

Import the same and Done!

Send (via post method) your image as an Base64 encoded String in JSON object along with any other data you have.

Comment: Note that `django-extra-fields` is deprecated! Use [drf-extra-fields](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields) instead

Answer (score 2):

There could be two best locations, depending on your use-case:

1. in your serializer you have the `validate_X` and `transform_X` methods you can override for your field (see the [validation docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#validation)) and to the conversion in both directions here.
2. write your own [custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#custom-fields) if you need the feature more often. You only have to define how the conversions run in both directions in `to_native` and `from_native`. Perhaps extend the original DRF [`ImageField`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L966) to keep the image-data validation with PIL.

**Update DRF3:**

`transform_X` methods replaced by `to_representation()`. See [removal-of-transform_field_name](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#removal-of-transform_field_name) and [Overriding serialization and deserialization behavior](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)
.

Also have a look at this DRF [Base64ImageFieldMixin](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields/blob/master/drf_extra_fields/fields.py#L32) example.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`django extra fields`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extra-fields). Use `Base64ImageField` as a serializer field assuming of course you used an `ImageField` in your models.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this field type in your serializer

```
class YourModelSerilizer(serializers.Serializer):
    image_field = Base64ImageField()
```

[Here is the proper guideline](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields)